# Persmissions required to query Permission sets and Permission set groups via Workbench

Tags: permissions, permission-sets, workbench, system-permissions

I have applied the Minimum access profile (+ 10 permissions below) to a user who authenticates the connection SF <> EC.

- List item
- List item
- View All Users
- View Setup and Configuration
- View All Custom
- Settings
- Modify Metadata Through Metadata API Functions
- Run Reports
- Author Apex
- API Enabled
- Manage All Private Reports and Dashboards
- Manage Sharing
- Manage Flow

At that point, in Workbench we see only custom permission sets and permission set groups.
I then applied further permissions described in the permission sets developer API doc at the top of the page in the section Special Access Rules, those are:

- Manage Session Permission Set Activations
- Assign Permission Sets
- Manage Profiles and Permission Sets

That did not change the number or type of Permission sets and Permission set groups synced (only custom).
After that, I applied Customize Application, View all data and still have not been able to sync the Standard Permission sets and Permission set groups.
Now I reviewed the list of all Administrative Permissions Permissions on the Profile level but I cannot see anything that rings a bell. What would you say should I do next, since I am stuck at this point?